# Use of # in answers/documentation when referring to methods of a class

Tags: java, object-oriented, documentation, methods

When looking through Java documentation or answers for Stack Overflow / programming forum questions, I often see people referring to methods like `String#format`, `Object#clone` etc, rather than `String.format`.

Is this something to do with it being a non-static method, or is this just some convention?

This is quite hard to search for due to most search engines ignoring the '#' symbol so I apologise if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of `String#format` comes from the javadocs and is seen there as `{@link package.class#member label}` (docs on [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link)).

The generated link to the javadoc for `String#format` is `<a href="../../java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)">format</a>` - the `#` being a [link to an anchor within the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1) - in this case, the `String.html` page and the `#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)` anchor.  You can see an example of this at [Oracle java docs for String#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) (note the url and poke around the generated html too)

Nothing more than the leaking of the documentation format out into... other documentation.